# Return properties from Web API based on permissions?

Tags: c#, json, api

Lets say I have a model I'll be returning from an endpoint:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make it so based on some criteria on the API key, I may or may not show Salary?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetEmployee(int id)
{
    if (permissions["api_key"].isAdmin = true) { 
        //include Salary
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await Employees.getEmployee(id));
    } else {
       //don't include salary
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, await Employees.getEmployee(id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Add parameter and call `Employees.getEmployee(id, isAdmin)` and fill Salary only if(isAdmin)?

b) Add to class Employee `public bool ShouldSerializeSalary() => Salary!=0;` (or other logic), [see](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

Comment: There's more than 1 flag, isAdmin is just one of them.  I'd be overloading a lot

Comment: You can use two different DTOs and map it to your model using tool like Automapper, to show only properties you want to show them bases on the API key or isAdmin flags.